# Как в Django загрузить файл, отправленный через js?

Tags: javascript, python, django

Как реализовать механизм загрузки файла в Django через Js (Angular 2)?
Не нашел толкового объяснения на данную тему, в основном все ссылаются на офф. документацию, где все показано через native views.

Comment: А какая для native views разница, через js вы загружаете или не через js? В любом случае это будет обыкновенный HTTP POST-запрос, который может принять обыкновенная вьюха, а отправлен он через js или нет, никакого значения не имеет. Со стороны джанги ничего особенного для загрузки из js делать не надо.

Answer (score 0):

Вот как делаю это я, но через обычный js. Посылаю POST запрос с файлом(в этом случае это изображение) на url "image-upload/" к примеру и потом сохраняю на диске, можно в БД будет еще проще.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^image-upload/$', views.image_upload, name='image_upload'),
]
```

views.py

```
import json
import os
import datetime

from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


def image_upload(request):
        if request.FILES:
            the_file = request.FILES['image']
            allowed_types = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/x-png', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
            if not the_file.content_type in allowed_types:
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'error': _('You can only upload images.')}),
                                    content_type="application/json")
            # Other data on the request.FILES dictionary:
            # filesize = len(file['content'])
            # filetype = file['content-type']
            upload_to = 'uploads/%d/%d/%d/' % (now_date.year, now_date.month, now_date.day)
            path = default_storage.save(os.path.join(upload_to, the_file.name), the_file)
            link = default_storage.url(path)
            # return JsonResponse({'link': link})
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'link': link}), content_type="application/json")
```